# Ajax.BeginForm refreshes the view instead of updating target id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My view

```
<div id="ValidationSummary">
     @Html.Partial("ValidationSummary")
</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", //<-- Action name
    "JobDetails", //<-- Controller name
     new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "ValidationSummary" }))
{

}
```

I want the ValidationSummary to replace. But it changes my url to JobDetails

Comment: did you add the related microsoft ajax javascript files correctly? It seems that your ajax call doesn't work. did you check it through the firebug(in firefox) or develper tools (in chrome/ie)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have added the following script to your page:

- `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

In ASP.NET MVC 3, jQuery is the default client side framework used for client side validation and Ajax.

Ajax helpers such as Ajax.BeginForm and Ajax.ActionLink emit HTML5 data-* attributes that are interpreted by the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script and AJAXified in this way.

Also make sure that you have removed all references to `Microsoft*.js` scripts. Those are obsolete and should no longer be used in ASP.NET MVC 3.